# Showing a complex function is nowhere differentiable in a certain disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function and I am asked to prove that it is nowhere differentiable on an open disc. I found the cauchy riemann equations and saw that is is satisfied at the origin. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Why not tell us what the function is?

Answer (score 1):

At any point where the CR hold, use the definition of the derivative as a limit to check if the function is differentiable or not.

Since you expect it not to be, check what happens along some curves.

Usually before going to the definition, one should check fast if the partial derivatives are continuous at that point. Is yes, you know the function is differentiable, if not you need to go to the definition.